# mysql join Get unjoined values too

Tags: mysql, join

The below query is based on my payments table. which joins with daily orders table. I have list of bill numbers in my daily table. with this query I get only bill number for which the payment has been made. Would like to get the complete list of bill numbers from daily table and if payment not received then the received column to be empty.And order them with Bill-no Ascending

```
create or replace view view_pymts
As SELECT p.`order-id`, p.`order-item-code`,daily.Bill_no,daily.tally_sku,daily.`quantity-purchased` as quantity,daily.`item-price`+daily.`shipping-price`as inv_value,daily.rma_rcvd_amt as return_value, round((SUM(p.amount) + z.other),2) AS received

FROM payments p
INNER JOIN daily ON p.`order-item-code`= daily.`order-item-id`
JOIN (
SELECT `order-id`, 
SUM(CASE WHEN `order-item-code` IS NULL
         THEN amount 
         ELSE 0.0 END) / (COUNT(DISTINCT `order-item-code`)) AS other 
FROM payments
GROUP BY `order-id`
) z
ON p.`order-id` = z.`order-id`
GROUP BY p.`order-id`, p.`order-item-code`
```

Comment: For all `bill-numbers` from `daily` table , you should do `daily LEFT JOIN payments` .

Comment: Using '-' in table/column identifiers is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`. This will make all missing fields `NULL` in the table on the right of the join (the table after the join statement, rather than the one before, which is said to be on the left of the join).

EDIT: I didn't read the question carefully enough, and @minatverma is correct. You could either use a `RIGHT JOIN` in place of your `INNER JOIN` (right join doing the opposite of a left join, making null the fields missing in the table on the left), or switch the order of your tables and use a `LEFT JOIN`.